# GPU printing None for machine learning layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am running the following code, Using tensorflow for GPU

```
import numpy as np

import keras

from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Dense, Reshape, Conv2DTranspose, Conv2D

input_img = keras.Input(shape=(144, 48, 1))

x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2,padding='same')(input_img)
print(x.shape)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding='same')(x)
print(x.shape)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 2, activation="relu", strides=2,padding='same')(x)
print(x.shape)
encoded = layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation="relu", strides=2,padding='same')(x)
print(encoded.shape)

encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)


encoded_input= keras.Input(shape=(9,3,64))
x = Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2,padding='same')(encoded_input)
print('transpose', x.shape)
x = Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2,padding='same')(x)
print('transpose',x.shape)
x = Conv2DTranspose(16, 3, activation="relu", strides=2,padding='same')(x)
print('transpose',x.shape)
decoded = Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="relu", strides=2,padding='same')(x)
print('transpose',decoded.shape)

decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoded)
```

But I got the following output when I print the shapes of each layer. The conv2d transpose layers is showing None.

```
(None, 72, 24, 64)
(None, 36, 12, 256)
(None, 18, 6, 128)
(None, 9, 3, 64)
(transpose, None, None, None, 64)
(transpose, None, None, None, 32)
(transpose, None, None, None, 16)
(transpose, None, None, None, 1)
```

In turn, I am getting wrong results from Running the model. On CPU, I do not have the None issues

Comment: Just for info, the "None" comes from Python, not Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this. Basically, I changed the

```
layers.Conv2D
```

to

```
Conv2D
```